# What is the order of execution for this SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have below SQL Query :

```
SELECT TOP 5 C.CustomerID,C.CustomerName,C.CustomerSalary
FROM Customer C
WHERE C.CustomerSalary > 10000
ORDER BY C.CustomerSalary DESC
```

What will be execution order of the following with proper explanation ?

> 1. TOP Clause
> 2. WHERE Clause
> 3. ORDER BY Clause

Comment: Not exactly, I have found so many different views of peoples about this. Just wanna confirm. :)

Comment: Are you asking about the logical execution order or the actual/physical order of execution?

Comment: Do you think there is difference between them?

Comment: Of course there can be great differences between the two! It's in the quoted paragraph, in the 18+ votes answer: **`Note that the actual physical execution of the statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this list.`**

Answer (score 64):

Check out [the documentation for the SELECT statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx), in particular this section:

> Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement
>
> The following steps show the logical processing order, or binding
>   order, for a SELECT statement. This order determines when the objects
>   defined in one step are made available to the clauses in subsequent
>   steps. For example, if the query processor can bind to (access) the
>   tables or views defined in the FROM clause, these objects and their
>   columns are made available to all subsequent steps. Conversely,
>   because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived
>   columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding
>   clauses. However, they can be referenced by subsequent clauses such as
>   the ORDER BY clause. **Note that the actual physical execution of the
>   statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary
>   from this list.**

which gives the following order:

```
FROM
ON
JOIN
WHERE
GROUP BY
WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
HAVING
SELECT
DISTINCT
ORDER BY
TOP
```

Comment: +1 You should emphasise **that the actual physical execution of the statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this list**. In practice I'd expect the order to most likely be `TOP`, `ORDER BY`, `WHERE` but noting that each step depends on the successive step so while `TOP` would **start** before `ORDER BY` which would **start** before `WHERE`, in practice `WHERE` would **finish** before `ORDER BY` which would **finish** before `TOP`. Read the execution plan: it goes from left to right.

Comment: The `ON` should not be on this list. It's used in the `FROM` clause but it doesn't stand on its own.

Comment: See this **[poster](http://www.sql.co.il/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf)** by [Itzik Ben-Gan](http://tsql.solidq.com/about.htm), a SQL-Server MVP with many published books about SQL-Server. (and even this poster has a small mistake, putting `TOP` before `ORDER BY`.)

Comment: [Here is a good example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487264/i-still-get-a-arithmetic-overflow-when-i-filter-on-a-cast-datetime-even-if-i-u) of how the order is not so set in stone (its a question of mine where I was getting bit by a cast happening before a filter).

Comment: does this Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement apply to MySQL?

Comment: @ta (logically) you can't determine what the top 5 rows are until you have ordered them. And you cannot order until you've whered the rows to keep.

Comment: @don logical order is well defined in SQL standard and all RDBMS follow it. Deviations can only lead to impossible or unexpected behavior (e.g. how would the sum function behave when used in where clause, since groups of rows haven't been created... they're created after where clause)

Comment: @SalmanA hah for it being so "well defined" when literally there's only 1 page on the internet (the Microsoft link) that definitively states what the logical order is (for SQL Server). No other RDBMS, no other documentation that I've come across, definitively states what the order is. And the order matters a LOT so it's pretty weird how uncommonly documented it is. We have 1 definitive Microsoft link (for SQL Server), and 0 for all other RDBMS... not remotely a consensus.

Comment: @don in my opinion, SQL concepts have no place in any RDBMS' documentation. But you're absolutely right about not finding anything about it on the internet. Here's an article that actually helps: https://blog.jooq.org/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/

Answer (score 15):

1. `WHERE`
2. `ORDER BY`
3. `TOP`

Here is a good article about that: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/

Answer (score 12):

Simply remember this phrase:-
    *Fred Jones' Weird Grave Has Several Dull Owls*

Take the first letter of each word, and you get this:-

```
FROM
(ON)
JOIN
WHERE
GROUP BY
(WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP)
HAVING
SELECT
DISTINCT
ORDER BY
TOP
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's missing window (analytic) functions.

Answer (score 11):

This is exact execution order, with your case.

```
1-FROM
2-WHERE
3-SELECT 
4-ORDER BY
5-TOP
```

Comment: is this the general execution order for all SQL/RDBMS? I know every RDBMS does it's own optimization, but can we at least depend on this logical order of steps when making rows available?

Answer (score 6):

TOP, WHERE, and ORDER BY are not "executed" - they simply describe the desired result and the database query optimizer determines (hopefully) the best plan for the actual execution. The separation between "declaring the desired result" and how it is physically achieved is what makes SQL a "declarative" language.

Assuming there is an index on `CustomerSalary`, and the table is **not** clustered, your query will likely be executed as an index seek + table heap access, as illustrated in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96e40/1) (click on *View Execution Plan* at the bottom):

[image]

As you can see, first the correct `CustomerSalary` value is found through the *Index Seek*, then the row that value belongs to is retrieved from the table heap through *RID Lookup* (Row ID Lookup). The *Top* is just for show here (and has 0% cost), as is the *Nested Loops* for that matter - the starting index seek will return (at most) one row in any case. The whole query is rather efficient and will likely cost only a few I/O operations.

If the table is [clustered](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index), you'll likely have another index seek instead of the table heap access, as illustrated in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79fab/1/0) (note the lack of NONCLUSTERED keyword in the DDL SQL):

[image]

But beware: I was lucky this time to get the "right" execution plan. The query optimizer might have chosen a full table scan, which is sometimes actually faster on small tables. When analyzing query plans, always try to do that on realistic amounts of data!

Answer (score 3):

Visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx for a better explanation.

The following steps show the logical processing order, or binding order, for a SELECT statement. This order determines when the objects defined in one step are made available to the clauses in subsequent steps. For example, if the query processor can bind to (access) the tables or views defined in the FROM clause, these objects and their columns are made available to all subsequent steps. Conversely, because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding clauses. However, they can be referenced by subsequent clauses such as the ORDER BY clause. Note that the actual physical execution of the statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this list.

**FROM**

**ON**

**JOIN**

**WHERE**

**GROUP BY**

**WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP**

**HAVING**

**SELECT**

**DISTINCT**

**ORDER BY**

**TOP**

Answer (score 2):

My $0,02 here.

There's two different concepts in action here: the logical execution order and the plan of query execution. An other was to see it is who answers the following questions:

1. How MSSQL understood my SQL Query?
2. What it'll do to execute it in the best possible way given the current schema and data?

The first question is answered by the logical execution order. [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17403990/10300) show what it is. It's the way SQL understood your command: "FROM Customer table (aliased as C) consider only the rows WHERE the C.CustomerSalary > 10000, ORDER them BY C.CustomerSalary in descendent order and SELECT the columns listed for the TOP 5 rows". The resultset will obey that meaning

The second question's answer is the query execution plan - and it depends on your schema (table definitions, selectivity of data, quantity of rows in the customer table, defined indexes, etc) since is heavily dependant of SQL Server optimizer internal workings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete sequence for sql server :

```
1.  FROM
2.  ON
3.  JOIN
4.  WHERE
5.  GROUP BY
6.  WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
7.  HAVING
8.  SELECT
9.  DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP
```

So from the above list, you can easily understand the execution sequence of **`TOP, WHERE and ORDER BY`** which is :

```
1.  WHERE
2.  ORDER BY
3.  TOP
```

[**Get more information about it from Microsoft**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)