# Cannot use Alias name in WHERE clause but can in ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why does this SQL not work?

The:

```
6371 * ACos( Cos(RADIANS(Latitude)) * Cos(RADIANS('50.017466977673905')) * Cos(RADIANS('24.69924272460935')
- RADIANS(Longitude)) + Sin(RADIANS(Latitude)) * Sin(RADIANS('50.017466977673905')) )
```

Clause just calculates the order from a search point.

Which I am aliasing (because it so longwinded) to Distance.

```
SELECT   [Hotel Id],
  latitude,
  longitude,
  establishmentname,
  6371 * ACos( Cos(RADIANS(Latitude)) * Cos(RADIANS('50.017466977673905')) * Cos(RADIANS('24.69924272460935') - RADIANS(Longitude)) + Sin(RADIANS(Latitude)) * Sin(RADIANS('50.017466977673905')) ) AS Distance  
FROM [dbo].[RPT_hotels] 
  WHERE distance < '30' 
  ORDER BY Distance
```

Here I replace the "Distance < 30" with the longwinded phrase and it works fine.

I can even ORDER BY the column alias and that works!!?

```
SELECT   [Hotel Id],
  latitude,
  longitude,
  establishmentname,
  6371 * ACos( Cos(RADIANS(Latitude)) * Cos(RADIANS('50.017466977673905')) * Cos(RADIANS('24.69924272460935') - RADIANS(Longitude)) + Sin(RADIANS(Latitude)) * Sin(RADIANS('50.017466977673905')) ) AS Distance  
FROM [dbo].[RPT_hotels] 
  WHERE 6371 * ACos( Cos(RADIANS(Latitude)) * Cos(RADIANS('50.017466977673905')) * Cos(RADIANS('24.69924272460935') - RADIANS(Longitude)) + Sin(RADIANS(Latitude)) * Sin(RADIANS('50.017466977673905')) ) < '30' 
  ORDER BY Distance
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because of natural query processing order, which is the following:

1. `FROM`
2. `ON`
3. `OUTER`
4. `WHERE`
5. `GROUP BY`
6. `CUBE` | `ROLLUP`
7. `HAVING`
8. `SELECT`
9. `DISTINCT`
10. `ORDER BY`
11. `TOP`

You're assigning your alias in `SELECT` statement. As you can see `WHERE` is processed before `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` comes after it. That's the reason. Now what are the workarounds:

- Subqueries. But they can be hard to read.
- `CROSS APPLY`. This should *beautify* your code a bit and is recommended method.

`CROSS APPLY` will assign alias before `WHERE` statement, making it usable in it.

```
SELECT [Hotel Id]
    , latitude
    , longitude
    , establishmentname
    , Distance
FROM [dbo].[RPT_hotels]
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 6371 * ACos(Cos(RADIANS(Latitude)) * Cos(RADIANS('50.017466977673905')) * Cos(RADIANS('24.69924272460935') - RADIANS(Longitude)) + Sin(RADIANS(Latitude)) * Sin(RADIANS('50.017466977673905')))
    ) AS T(Distance)
WHERE distance < 30
ORDER BY Distance;
```

If you want to find out more. Please read this question: [What is the order of execution for this SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403935/what-is-the-order-of-execution-for-this-sql-statement)

Answer (score 2):

As to why you can't specify an alias in the `WHERE` clause, this is due to the logical order of query processing: (http://tsql.solidq.com/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf).

The `WHERE` clause is processed after the `SELECT` clause but `ORDER BY` is processed afterward.  Column aliases can only be referenced after the `SELECT` clause has been processed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use an inner select like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        [Hotel Id],latitude,longitude,establishmentname,6371 * ACos( Cos(RADIANS(Latitude)) * Cos(RADIANS('50.017466977673905')) * Cos(RADIANS('24.69924272460935') - RADIANS(Longitude)) + Sin(RADIANS(Latitude)) * Sin(RADIANS('50.017466977673905')) ) AS Distance 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[RPT_hotels] ) t
WHERE Distance < 30 
ORDER BY Distance;
```

Note that `ORDER BY` can use aliases and column number also.

Another way is using `CTE` like this:

```
;WITH t AS (
    SELECT
        [Hotel Id],latitude,longitude,establishmentname,6371 * ACos( Cos(RADIANS(Latitude)) * Cos(RADIANS('50.017466977673905')) * Cos(RADIANS('24.69924272460935') - RADIANS(Longitude)) + Sin(RADIANS(Latitude)) * Sin(RADIANS('50.017466977673905')) ) AS Distance 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[RPT_hotels] )
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE Distance < 30
ORDER BY Distance;
```

Comment: In my opinion: No ;).

Answer (score 0):

It is the way it works. Note that ORDER BY Clause is applied after generating the entire data so the engine knows the alias name but WHERE clause does not know it until you use a derived table

```
select * from
(
SELECT   [Hotel Id],latitude,longitude,establishmentname,6371 * 
ACos( Cos(RADIANS(Latitude)) * Cos(RADIANS('50.017466977673905')) * 
Cos(RADIANS('24.69924272460935') - RADIANS(Longitude)) + 
Sin(RADIANS(Latitude)) * Sin(RADIANS('50.017466977673905')) ) AS Distance
FROM [dbo].[RPT_hotels] 
) as t
WHERE Distance < '30' ORDER BY Distance
```

Comment: You've somehow double-posted. I'd suggest deleting the other answer. If you're not aware of it, you can edit your answers as well.

Comment: Yes I found it and deleted the first one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ORDER BY clause is processed after the SELECT fields, in parsing. So, when it will order the clause, the alias are known but when it will filter by WHERE clause, they are not.

Try surrouding with another SELECT clause and move the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses to it.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...) WHERE ... ORDER BY ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clause is being processed before the SELECT clause and because of that **you can't use any alias in the WHERE clause**.
The ORDER BY clause is being processed after the SELECT, so you can use aliases there.

Answer (score 0):

`OREDER BY` is the final section of query processing. `WHERE` is far before that. For that reason you can not use aliases into the `WHERE` clause, but can use them inside the `ORDER BY`.

See [this link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/) for details about query processing order.