# How to use order by on a calculated field in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select, sql-order-by

How to use order by on a calculated field in SQL?

```
select a.Customer
    ,a.PlanTo
    ,a.Dollar01
    ,a.Dollar02
    ,a.Dollar03
    ,a.Dollar04
    ,a.Dollar05
    ,a.Dollar06
    ,a.Dollar07
    ,a.Dollar08
    ,a.Dollar09
    ,a.Dollar10
    ,a.Dollar11
    ,a.Dollar12
    ,(CAST(a.Dollar01 as decimal) + CAST(a.Dollar02 as decimal) 
    + CAST(a.Dollar03 as decimal) + CAST(a.Dollar04 as decimal) 
    + CAST(a.Dollar05 as decimal) + CAST(a.Dollar06 as decimal) 
    + CAST(a.Dollar07 as decimal) + CAST(a.Dollar08 as decimal) 
    + CAST(a.Dollar09 as decimal) + CAST(a.Dollar10 as decimal) 
    + CAST(a.Dollar11 as decimal) + CAST(a.Dollar12 as decimal)) as TOTAL1
from MDM_STAT.sds.SMarginText a
where a.salesyear = '2016'
order by a.total1
```

This is giving me 'Total1' column does not exist but as you see I have created it and is working if I am not using the `order by` clause.

Comment: Remove the alias `a.` -- try `order by total1`...

Comment: `a.total1` doesn't exist, since SQL Server will look for that column in `SMarginText `, but `ORDER BY TOTAL1;` would work just fine.

Comment: (1) Format your code and (2) Clarify (tags) which DBMS you are actually using - is it PostgreSQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks.. It works now. Also removed the postgresql tag

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do what Mureinik suggests and use the ordinal notation of `ORDER BY 13`, which means "order by the 13th column."  However, I would tend to avoid it because it's difficult to tell what you're *intending* to order by if you come back later.  Also, if you need to add a column or change the order, you have to remember to update the ORDER BY clause.  It's easy to miss that.

As others mention in the comments, it is possible to use the alias you specify in the ORDER BY.  However, because it's a column alias, there's nothing to fully qualify.  `a.TOTAL1` doesn't mean anything.  You must `ORDER BY TOTAL1`:

```
select a.Customer
    ,a.PlanTo
    ,a.Dollar01
    ,a.Dollar02
    ,a.Dollar03
    ,a.Dollar04
    ,a.Dollar05
    ,a.Dollar06
    ,a.Dollar07
    ,a.Dollar08
    ,a.Dollar09
    ,a.Dollar10
    ,a.Dollar11
    ,a.Dollar12
    ,(CAST(a.Dollar01 as decimal) + CAST(a.Dollar02 as decimal) 
    + CAST(a.Dollar03 as decimal) + CAST(a.Dollar04 as decimal) 
    + CAST(a.Dollar05 as decimal) + CAST(a.Dollar06 as decimal) 
    + CAST(a.Dollar07 as decimal) + CAST(a.Dollar08 as decimal) 
    + CAST(a.Dollar09 as decimal) + CAST(a.Dollar10 as decimal) 
    + CAST(a.Dollar11 as decimal) + CAST(a.Dollar12 as decimal)) as TOTAL1
from MDM_STAT.sds.SMarginText a
where a.salesyear = '2016'
order by total1
```

This works because of the query solve order.  `ORDER BY` is solved after the `SELECT`, unlike `WHERE` or `FROM` which are solved before the `SELECT` and therefore can't refer to column aliases in SQL Server.

This can be confusing or ambiguous if your column alias has the same name as a column from a table, so you need to be aware of that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This was pretty helpful in understanding how the clauses work. Appreciate it.

Comment: @RahulBanerjee It is helpful to know the order queries are executed.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17403990/696808) is greater detail on that, if you're interested.

Answer (score 5):

Posting Aaron Bertrand's comment as a community wiki, as I think it's the most straight forward answer:

`a.total1` doesn't exist, since SQL Server will look for that column in `SMarginText` , but `ORDER BY TOTAL1;` would work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use the column's number in the select list instead of its name: `ORDER BY 13`.

Comment: [Such a terrible idea to recommend, especially for production code, since ordinals are very brittle](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal.aspx). In other news, the easiest way to wash your dishes is to throw them away and buy new ones. ("Easiest" and "best" rarely coincide.)

Comment: Aaron Bertrand, the link to your blog's archive is dead. I don't really need it but you might want to know.