Unknown column [col_name] in 'order clause'
Select CONCAT ( Name, '(' , LEFT(occupation,1) , ')'   )
FROM occupations
UNION
Select 
CONCAT ('There are  a total of  ', Count(Occupation) ,' ', occupation, 's' ) as line
FROM occupations
Group by occupation
ORDER by line

Why can I not use 'line' in Order by even though it is in Select statement and gets executed before. I can use it correctly without the UNION but once I use UNION statement it is not working and I also tried Order by Count(occupation) it did not work

use Count(Occupation)  instead of line to get the same effect

I did try that, no change

I cannot make any sense of what you are trying to do. The column name is taken from the columns in the first select of a union, so add an alias to the expression in the first select and sort by that. If you are trying to sort just the second select then put parentheses around the whole of the second select statement.

This fiddle might help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/DmQUKxu2

see similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749844/how-to-use-order-by-on-a-calculated-field-in-sql

Why can I not use 'line' in Order by even though it is in Select statement and gets executed before. Study carefully: Result Set Column Names and Data Types and Set Operations with ORDER BY and LIMIT

I think that you must use not UNION but GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP accompanied by GROUPING(). Or at least not UNION which is UNION DISTINCT and causes excess lines sorting which may reorder the output lines but UNION ALL which saves the lines ordering produced by each separate subquery. From the other side your task is not clear now - provide a sample (source data and desired output) according to Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, paragraphs 5 and 3.


Why can I not use 'line' in Order by ...

The question here is about the "why", rather than asking how to solve the issue, so I'll focus on that first.
Remember that database tables (relations) are, by definition, unordered sets. Therefore, when you use UNION, the ORDER BY only has any meaning relative to the entire query. You cannot order by one of the component queries that make up the UNION, because the other component is not ordered and until an ORDER BY is applied the result of the UNION is not ordered.
Furthermore, the column names of a component query within a UNION have no meaning for the result as a whole. For example, you can UNION two SELECT queries using columns with different names in the same position. When there is a conflict, the names from first component of the UNION are used. Likewise, other source columns from the tables/queries used in a UNION no longer have any meaning after the UNION (unless included as part of the UNION).
Therefore, the ORDER BY expression from the question MUST only be in reference to a column defined for the UNION as a whole, not just the 2nd component, and at this point the line column no longer exists (it was absorbed into the larger UNION).
I can hear it now: "But I want the order on the second query and don't care about the first."
That's not allowed. If you don't care about the order in the first part of the query, then the entire order is non-deterministic and the database is free to order the entire result in whatever way it finds most efficient. Furthermore, you aren't even allowed to assume it will show results from the first component of the UNION before later components of the UNION (this may often happen, but it's not guaranteed!). If you care about the order at all, you MUST have an ORDER BY for the entire result set.
The common solution to avoid this confusion nests the UNION into a larger SELECT query, and do all your ORDER BY with the outer query. Additionally, you can use an extra column projection if you need to sort one component before another:
SELECT Line
FROM (
    select concat( Name, '(' , LEFT(occupation,1) , ')'   ) as Line
       , 0 as Ordinal
    from occupations

    union

    select 
    concat('There are  a total of  ', count(Occupation) ,' ', occupation, 's' ) 
        , 1 as Ordinal
    from occupations
    group by occupation
) t
ORDER BY Ordinal, Line

See it here (with appreciation to the other answer saving me time on the fiddle):

https://dbfiddle.uk/RnABtt2U


You are welcome to use the fiddle I contributed for collaborative use.  Your description of the problem is fascinating and far more detailed then I expected. Thank you.

If you want to use "ORDER BY Line" then you must embed your query as a sub-query. This forces the value of Line to be fully calculated before the ORDER BY clause is evaluated.
CREATE TABLE occupations
(
   `occupation` VARCHAR(50),
   `Name` VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO occupations (`occupation`,   `Name` ) VALUES
  ('Writer','John'),
  ('Driver', 'Sam');

SELECT * FROM occupations;

SELECT * FROM
(
    Select CONCAT ( Name, '(' , LEFT(occupation,1) , ')' ) as line, occupation, 1 as linetype
    FROM occupations 

    UNION
  
    Select CONCAT ('There are a total of ', Count(Occupation) ,' ', occupation, 's' ) as line, occupation, 2 as linetype
    FROM occupations 
    Group by occupation
) t
ORDER BY line

fiddle



line
occupation
linetype




Sam(D)
Driver
1


John(W)
Writer
1


There are a total of 1 Drivers
Driver
2


There are a total of 1 Writers
Writer
2




LineType column provided in case we misunderstood your desired output. Use "ORDER BY LineType, Line" to get the subtotal to appear after each occupation type.

The value of Line is not fully calculated by the time the ORDER BY clause is evaluated by the optimizer/compiler. You can use the ordinal notation of ORDER BY 1, which means "order by whatever the 1st column is eventually calculated as". This strategy is usually avoided because it is NOT well known and NOT intuitive. Also, it is dangerous. The column order may change without realizing the ordinal in the ORDER BY clause must also be adjusted.
Select CONCAT ( Name, '(' , LEFT(occupation,1) , ')' ) as line, occupation, 1 as linetype
FROM occupations 

UNION
  
Select CONCAT ('There are a total of ', Count(Occupation) ,' ', occupation, 's' ) as line, occupation, 2 as linetype
FROM occupations 
Group by occupation
ORDER BY 1  

Fiddle

I know it's legal, but I'm not a fan of ordering by ordinal column expressions.

I agree. This sucks and should never be used professionally. But there is value in knowing this option exists, why it works, and why it is not recommended.

This also works. Thanks for the research recommendations Akina  Set Operations with ORDER BY and LIMIT
If one or more individual statements make use of ORDER BY, LIMIT, or both, and, in addition, you wish to apply an ORDER BY, LIMIT, or both to the entire result, then each such individual statement must be enclosed in parentheses.
When in doubt try more parentheses!
(Select CONCAT ( Name, '(' , LEFT(occupation,1) , ')' ) as line, occupation, 1 as linetype
FROM occupations 
ORDER BY LINE) 
UNION
(Select CONCAT ('There are a total of ', Count(Occupation) ,' ', occupation, 's' ) as line, occupation, 2 as linetype
FROM occupations 
Group by occupation
ORDER BY Line)

fiddle

Try using the ORDER BY clause in outer query for UNION. e.g.
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        CONCAT ( Name,  '(' , LEFT(occupation, 1) , ')' ) AS line, occupation
    FROM occupations
    UNION
    SELECT
        CONCAT ('There are a total of ', Count(occupation) , ' ', occupation,'s' ) AS line, occupation
    FROM
        occupations
    GROUP BY occupation
)T
ORDER BY T.line


I get an error with your SQL : In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'fiddle.occupations.occupation'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by  https://dbfiddle.uk/LhVIvPHE

My bad, I have a corrected version working on the this link: https://dbfiddle.uk/PPRuTjYq

I have corrected the answer above as well.
