# How to get multiple average values using subqueries

Tags: sql-server

There are many accountants and each of them has jobs (paid by the hour) and I need to get the accountant name of  every accountant who has an average job cost higher than the overall average of job costs. How do I do this?

```
SELECT Accountant_Name, AVG(job_cost) as 'Average'
FROM job_view
WHERE Average > (SELECT AVG (job_cost) AS AV
FROM job_view)
GROUP BY Accountant_Name;
```

Everything needed is in a view named the job_view. The above code is not working any help on modifications would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you are getting with above code?

Comment: Invalid column name 'Average'

Comment: the 'Average' ALIAS for the `AVG(Job_Cost)` column is not visible in the `WHERE` clause. Which is why you could try replacing it with the `AVG(Job_Cost)`, but then you'll get that windowed functions can exist only in `HAVING` and `SELECT` parts of the query. Just take a look at my answer on how to solve all of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
SELECT Accountant_Name
    , AVG(Job_Cost) as 'Average'
FROM Job_View
GROUP BY Accountant_Name
HAVING AVG(Job_Cost) > (SELECT AVG(Job_Cost) FROM Job_View)
```

As per your comment, the error you're getting at `WHERE Average >` is because the alias `Average` is not visible in a `WHERE` clause and usually requires you to put the entire contents of the column just as you defined it in the `SELECT` part.

But because in the `SELECT` part the `Average` column is a aggregate function, these can only go lower in the `HAVING` section, because `HAVING` handles filtering of aggregate conditions.

Why all this? Because there are rules for order of execution of statements in a query, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17403990/1266737).

Comment: It worked with the GROUP BY clause added thank you but I tried the same thing with WHERE instead of HAVING then it still gave me a error. Any chance you could tell me why that was?

Answer (score 1):

You'll still need to Group by Accountant_Name

```
SELECT Accountant_Name, AVG(job_cost) as 'Average'
    FROM job_view
    GROUP BY Accountant_Name
    Having AVG(job_cost) > (SELECT AVG (job_cost) FROM job_view);
```