# SQL Server Rank() and Group by

Tags: sql-server, group-by, rank

Here is my example

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d158d/4)

My data (table_1)

```
col_1
foo
foo
bar
bar
```

My queries:

```
select col_1, rank() over(order by col_1) as rank from table_1;
```

returns:

```
col_1 rank
foo    1
foo    1
bar    3
bar    3
```

and this query returns

```
select col_1, rank() over(order by col_1) as rank from table_1 group by col_1

col_1 rank
foo    1
bar    2
```

So if I understand correctly `rank` is executed only after `group by` clause and `order` next to `rank` is also only executed after `group by` clause.

**Update**

In case SQLFiddle does not run, here is query I used to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1  
    (
     col_1 varchar(30)
    );

INSERT INTO table_1
(col_1)
VALUES
('foo'),
('foo'),
('bar'),
('bar')
;
```

Comment: No it doesn't work like that. Are you sure you got those results in SQLFiddle? (not accessible for me). It should do the ranking by ordering on col_1. That is bar would be 1 and foo 3 in first and bar:1 foo:2 in second. Maybe you used desc. In second one grouping is done and then the select (as with any other select).

Comment: @CetinBasoz, Thank you for reply! Yes, this is how it works in SQLFiddle, and I am a bit puzzled, I was expecting `rank` and `order` to be always executed prior to `group by`. SQLFiddle works for me, just takes a minute to load.

Comment: that sqlfiddle link crashed for me also. Can you just post the details here?

Comment: just `SELECT` is executed after `GROUP BY`, you can google `actual execution order in sql server` or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403935/what-is-the-order-of-execution-for-this-sql-statement

Comment: @SeanLange There are no details to post, except you need to create table_1 shown in the post. (create and insert...). Oh, one thing, this is sql server 2017

Comment: Why is it so hard to post the table and data here? You already did it once right? It is copy and paste for you.

Comment: @SeanLange, I just updated post with `create` and `insert` statement. Now post has everything that SQLFiddle has. I am not sure if my update is helpful, but here it is anyway.

Comment: `So if I understand correctly rank is executed only after group by clause` - your understanding is correct, but what is your question? `rank()` is a window function, those by design are calculated over the final resultset, not over the original one. That is why they may only appear in `select` and cannot appear in `where`. `and order next to rank is also only executed after group by clause` - that is also correct, but your example result is not correct, you could not get `1` against `foo` and `2` against `bar`, it is the other way round, unless you used `order by col_1 desc`.

Comment: I am guessing that what you want as a result is bar 1, foo 3. Only those two rows. Just add a distinct to your first query.

Comment: There is no question I think, or the question is why SQLFiddle result is wrong. Interestingly it opened quite easily now and the result is correct unlike what you told us it returned as a result. SQLFidlle correctly lists bar first foo second. And if this is a question, as I said in my first reply, in SQL group by executes before the select.