# How to calculate and apply condition on the age calculated based on date of birth in mysql?

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am calculating the user's age based upon his dob as :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(now(),u.date_of_birth)), '%Y')+0 AS Age from users u ;
```

And it is giving me the correct age . Now how can I apply condition to . For eg when I am trying to do it,it is giving me error :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(now(),u.date_of_birth)), '%Y')+0 AS Age from users u where age>20;
```

I know this syntax is incorrect but how can I apply condition to it in mysql and in JPA at Java side.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use alias `Age` there directly in `Where` clause at it is not calculated at that stage. Instead, you need to use full expression (the same one you're using to calculate age in `Select` clause).

Following query should work:

```
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(now(),u.date_of_birth)), '%Y')+0 AS Age 
   from users u 
   where DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(now(),u.date_of_birth)), '%Y')+0 >20;
```

I think to understand this even better, you should know how an `SQL` query actually getting executed. Please go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17403990/2225030) for the same.

Additionally, I think calculating `Age` at 2 places in same query is not the best way to do this. Suppose you have a unique column in table `Users`, and let's call it `Id`. Now, you can accomplish same with a better approach with following query :

```
Select u2.Id, u2.age
from users u1
inner join 
          (select id,
                  DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(now(),u.date_of_birth)), '%Y')+0 AS Age 
           from users
          ) u2
On u1.id = u2.id
where u2.age > 20
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To used it sql query in Java you need a **preparedStatement** or a **statement**. For prepared statement use those lines:

```
String sql = "SELECT * 
             FROM users
             WHERE date_of_birth > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL ? YEAR);"

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

preparedStatement.setInt(1, "20");
preparedStatement.executeQuery(sql);
```

Your query should be this one :

```
SELECT date_of_birth    
FROM users
WHERE date_of_birth > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 20 YEAR);
```